# import project from eclipse to android studio

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

I explain my systems :

- Operation System : Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 Ltd)
- Eclipse Luna
- Android SDK 24.6
- Android Studio Latest Version Since Now
- Country : i should say that my country is filtered from google (some necacery service ) , and i 
  have not proxy

i export my eclipse project to gradle , and import them to android studio .
i think every thing is okey . but , i can't run my project .
can anybody share something .
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

No need to export anything. You can just directly open the Eclipse project from Android Studio.

Comment: all of my project , import to android-studio in one modular . and i can not run it , can you say something about this ?

Comment: Could be for many different reasons. Load each Eclipse project in workspace in a separate module, and configure the dependencies accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue!
i solved it!
 Just recreate the same activites and copy and paste those code from ur eclipse created project to android studio project!
change package names etc.. and run!

Reason: Eclipse uses different Build system. And Android Studio uses Gradle Build System! 
I think there might be a Grade plugin for Eclipse! not sure!

Comment: i check your advise , and tell you if it's good to me . thanks

Comment: @adnan9011: sure! Lemme know